# Visual Studio 2015 + Webpack generated bundles + Publish == missing files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, webpack, publish

When using **Visual Studio 2015** & **Webpack**, Webpack generates a bundle like **"[name].[chunkhash].js"**

so this generated bundle will not be included in the solution, then when we **publish** the project this **new bundle** will **not be published**, because it is **not included in the solution**.

What is the best way to handle newly generated files outside of visual studio?

Am i forced to manually include this new file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To publish folder which are not "included" in the VS-Solution do:

. right click the solution -> unload project

. right click -> edit csproj file

. add following code

```
<Content Include="FolderToInclude\**">
<Visible>false</Visible>
</Content>
```

. save file, close it, right click solution -> reload project

---

now whenever you publish you code the folder will be published too, but remember that the folder will not be visible in your solution
ps. "false" is on purpose to hide it in the solution, so that the folder will be not altered by an user.

Comment: What if the file is not there before you click the "Publish" button (generated before build task)?